# How can I programatically detect ASP.NET 3.5?

Tags: asp.net-3.5

I am creating a diagnostic page for ASP.NET and would like to programatically detect if ASP.NET 3.5 has been installed on the server.  Any ideas on how to best do this?

Comment: can you correct the spelling of your question title? :)

Comment: I really liked the first version!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System.Environment.Version gives you the CLR version.

For ASP.NET 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5 it will return the same CLR version: 2.0.50727.3053

As for ASP.NET 4.0 the CLR version will change to 4.*